# Como fazer a função toggle do jQuery em javascript puro?

Tags: javascript, jquery, array

Descobri a pouco tempo e achei bem interessante a função toggle usando funções:

```
$('body').toggle(
    function(){
        alert('A')
    }, function(){
        alert('B')
    }
);
```

(No exemplo eu coloquei só 2 funções, eu queria com várias)

Tentei fazer em [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) mais não consegui (até olhei no código do [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery), mas lá é muito complicado).

## Explicação:

Já que a função toggle não vai usar elementos do DOM, ele poderia funcionar por meio de strings:

```
toggle('D', fn, fn, fn);
```

assim toda vez que `D` for mencionado no `arguments[0]` ele vai executar uma função por vez do array `D` (D é uma array de funções), caso não existir `D` ele cria uma nova array com as funções passadas para o `toggle()` e vai funcionando normalmente. (No jQuery eles fazem isso com data nos elementos).

Comment: Poderia especificar o objetivo para que entendamos o que realmente você quer fazer, e qual o seu problema? Qual o sentido do seu código?

Comment: Tenho um aplicativo que não usa jQuery, e lá tem função do código que poderia muito bem usar esse método. Faz mais ou menos uma semana que tento fazer mão não consigo, então queria a ajuda de alguém que entendesse melhor...

Comment: Quer fazer o toggle sem o uso de jQuery ? ok vou editar minha resposta

Comment: Só uma informação, essa função foi removida do jQuery a partir da versão 1.9

Comment: eu estava tentando olhar na versão 1.7.2 (muita gente gosta dessa versão então sempre olho nela rsrsrs)

Comment: @IagoBruno eu editei minha resposta incluindo uma solução javascript que você pode alterar a ordem e atribui as funções via Array's facilitando a dinamicidade do código.

Comment: o que seria `arguments[0]` por acaso é um argumento de URL?

Comment: poderia ser um código para especificar qual é o array, se for D, ele vai executar uma função por vez do array D, se for 'Hr' ele vai executar uma função por vez do 'Hr', caso não exista o array 'Hr', ele cria um novo array com as funções passadas para toggle

Comment: entendi! vou editar minha resposta :)

Comment: @IagoBruno fiz como você falou, encare o meu "aryFunctions" como se fosse o seu "D" :) porém a parte de criar um array se não haver funções não faria parte da função, você teria que checar se o array estiver vazio ou for nulo e criar outro, de acordo como voce quiser

Comment: acho que já está bom para mim, verificar se é função, se está vazio, não é problema

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basta você manter um contador circular, que pega o próximo evento de uma lista cada vez que o elemento for clicado:

```
function toggle() {
    var eventos = arguments;
    var contador = -1;
    return function() {
        contador = (contador + 1) % eventos.length;
        eventos[contador].apply(this, arguments);
    };
}

// Exemplo de uso:
document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = toggle(
    function() { alert("A"); }, 
    function() { alert("B"); }, 
    ...
);
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/rrJ6z/1/). É bom mesmo ter uma implementação alternativa, já que essa modalidade do método `.toggle` [está obsoleta](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) (e já foi removida nas versões recentes do jQuery).

Notas:

1. Optei por incrementar o contador **antes** de chamar a função, para no caso dela lançar uma exceção o método não ficar "preso" em um item só...
2. A implementação sugerida é bem genérica, podendo ser usada para outras coisas além do evento `onclick`. Como ela repassa `this` e `arguments` para cada item da lista, ela pode ser usada no lugar de qualquer função com qualquer assinatura.

---

**Atualização:** pelo que entendi após a pergunta ser editada (não está claro pra mim o que pretende), você quer que a função alterne entre os argumentos da lista sempre que ela for chamada com o primeiro argumento idêntico, é isso? Se for, creio que não há alternativa a não ser guardar seu "mapa de funções" em uma global:

```
var funcoesToggle = { };
function toggle(qual) {
    if ( !funcoesToggle[qual] )
        funcoesToggle[qual] = { 
            contador: -1,
            funcoes: Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1, arguments.length)
        };

    var escolhido = funcoesToggle[qual];
    escolhido.contador = (escolhido.contador + 1) % escolhido.funcoes.length;
    escolhido.funcoes[escolhido.contador]();
}

// Exemplo de uso:
toggle("D", function() { alert("A"); }, function() { alert("B"); }, function() { alert("C"); }); // A
toggle("D", function() { alert("A"); }, function() { alert("B"); }, function() { alert("C"); }); // B
toggle("Ee", function() { alert("A"); }, function() { alert("B"); }, function() { alert("C"); }); // A
toggle("D", function() { alert("A"); }, function() { alert("B"); }, function() { alert("C"); }); // C
toggle("Ee", function() { alert("A"); }, function() { alert("B"); }, function() { alert("C"); }); // B
```

[Exemplo no jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgibsonbr/rrJ6z/2/). Note que apenas a primeira vez que se usa uma string é que você precisa passar a lista de funções, nas seguintes basta chamar com um único argumento (embora isso tire um pouco o propósito da função, né?) De qualquer forma, eu **recomendo fortemente** usar o código da resposta original - é mais claro, e não "mistura as responsabilidades" (i.e. criar uma lista de funções para o "toggle" / usar essa lista de funções).

Comment: Funcionou muito bem! Mas não vou usar com elementos do DOM =p estava pensando assim: toggle('D', fn, fn, fn); assim ele executava uma função por ver quando 'D' fosse mencionado, ou 'Ee' e assim por diante

Comment: Teria como fazer isso? =p

Comment: @IagoBruno Atualizei minha resposta com um esclarecimento quanto ao uso sem elementos do DOM. Mas não entendi o que quer dizer com "quando 'D' fosse mencionado". Poderia editar a pergunta esclarecendo o que quer fazer?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta..

Comment: Era isso que eu queria \õõõõ/ **Obrigado =D**

Answer (score 2):

em JQuery seria isto:

```
$('body').toggle(
    function(){
        alert('A')
    }, function(){
        alert('B')
    }, function(){
        alert('C')
    }, function(){
        alert('D')
    }
);
```

Ou seja, várias funções atribuídas ao corpo do seu documento seguindo uma ordem de execução.

Porém você quer em Javascript puro, eu aproveitei e também te proporcionei uma **possibilidade de escolha de ordem**, que seria no caso alterando o parametro da função `toggle()` das funções `A`,`B`,`C`, e `D` você poderia fazer qual ordem quiser, ou repetir alguma função sem ter que incluir funções iguais novamente.

Essa seria a função toggle:

```
function toggle(aryFunctions,idx){
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].onclick = aryFunctions[idx];
}
```

E para utilizar declaramos um array de functions:

```
function A(){
  alert('A');
  toggle(aryFunctions,1);
}
function B(){
  alert('B');
  toggle(aryFunctions,2);
}
function C(){
  alert('C');
  toggle(aryFunctions,3);
}
function D(){
  alert('D');
  toggle(aryFunctions,0);
}
var aryFunctions = [A,B,C,D];

document.body.setAttribute("onclick","toggle(aryFunctions,0)");
```

Assim executaria:

> `A,B,C,D`

Seria a forma correta circular em ordem, e estou atribuindo o clique à tag `<body>` de seu html por isso não utilizando DOM.

Você pode mudar a ordem dinamicamente alterando o código das funções passadas.

**Você também pode facilitar seu trabalho de adicionar funções dinamicamente colocando-as no `aryFunctions` que seria um Array tornando seu trabalho bem mais fácil neste quesito.**

Veja, se eu mudar as funções do array para:

```
function A(){
  alert('A');
  toggle(aryFunctions,3);
}
function B(){
  alert('B');
  toggle(aryFunctions,2);
}
function C(){
  alert('C');
  toggle(aryFunctions,0);
}
function D(){
  alert('D');
  toggle(aryFunctions,1);
}
var aryFunctions = [A,B,C,D];

document.body.setAttribute("onclick","toggle(aryFunctions,0)");
```

Assim executaria:

> `A,D,B,C`

Desta maneira você tem bastante liberdade para fazer o tal `toggle()` como preferir.

Comment: estou editando minha resposta para colocar a solução em javascript puro

Comment: Isso! mas não querendo complicar, o código não vai usar elementos do DOM =/ pode ser por meio de strings...